# Make a draggable black box

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm trying to make a black box which I can click and drag but I seem to be stuck. Could anybody help me see where I'm going wrong?

```
def main_game():
    import pygame
    import math
    from time import *

    pygame.init()

    displayWidth = 268
    displayHeight = 552

    cyan = (0,255,255)
    red = (255,0,0)
    dark_red = (150,0,0)
    black = (0,0,0)
    grey = (200,200,200)
    dark_cyan = (0,230,230)

    my_rect = pygame.Rect([100,100,100,100])

    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth,displayHeight))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Test')

    pygame.display.update()

    gameExit = False
```

Main game loop:

```
    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print event
            gameDisplay.fill(grey)

            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, my_rect)

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                ExitFunction()

            pygame.display.update()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                is_inside = my_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

                if is_inside == 1:
                    gameExit = True
                    DragScreen()
```

This is one of my futile attempts, I created a new function to try to position the rectangle to the the coordinates of my mouse.

```
def DragScreen():
    import pygame
    from time import *

    pygame.init()

    displayWidth = 268
    displayHeight = 552

    cyan = (0,255,255)
    red = (255,0,0)
    dark_red = (150,0,0)
    black = (0,0,0)
    grey = (200,200,200)
    dark_cyan = (0,230,230)

    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth, displayHeight))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Test')

    pygame.display.update()

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print event
            gameDisplay.fill(grey)

            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, pygame.mouse.get_pos())

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                ExitFunction()
```

I will add a pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP event to stop the dragging of the box

```
            pygame.display.update()
```

I created this function, simply exit out when it is called (it works fine).

```
def ExitFunction():
    import pygame
    from time import*

    pygame.init()

    pygame.quit()
    quit()


    pygame.quit()
    quit()
main_game()
```

Comment: You're code is so segmented, I can't read it. I can help you but I'll have to start from scratch.

Comment: Thats fine I just want to figure this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, you can test for a click on the object. And move the object to the mouse's position:

```
################################################################################
# Imports ######################################################################
################################################################################

from pygame.locals import *
import pygame, os, sys

################################################################################
# Screen Setup #################################################################
################################################################################

pygame.init()
scr = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption('Box Test')

################################################################################
# Make Square ##################################################################
################################################################################

surf = pygame.Surface((64, 64)); surf.fill((255, 0, 0))
rect = surf.get_rect(); rect.center = (320, 240)

################################################################################
# Game Loop ####################################################################
################################################################################

while True:
    pygame.display.update()
    scr.fill((0, 0, 0))
    scr.blit(surf, rect)

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        if rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

################################################################################
################################################################################
################################################################################
```